# Excel Index and Match Multiple Criteria with Approximate Match

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match, approximate

I have searched around for a while and could not come up with an answer to my problem.  I am using a multi-criteria index and match function.  With multi-criteria formulas (3 or more criteria) I have only seen help online for exact matches.  In my case, I am actually looking for an approximate value in 1 criteria out of the 3.

This for a warehouse environment and I need to use an approx match to keep associates in the same area for the report. Otherwise by not including the description, the first result would be first match on the full list. This report will be used for all locations so sorting for each individual line is not a good option.

My formula is

`=INDEX(G:G,MATCH(1,(1<P:P)*(0=J:J),0))`

In the image, highlighted in yellow is my expect result row and the formula using the approx match should return value `B-010-018-208D`.  This is a snipped of the data which will be over 100k lines.  I cannot change the current formula to -1 or 1 at the end for match type since only 2 out of the 3 criteria (3rd criteria would be approx of value in cell `D3` from the image) needs to be the approx one.  Any ideas?

[image: User's image]

Comment: My formula got cut off in the original post, its =INDEX(G:G,MATCH(1,(1<P:P)*(0=J:J),0)).  I am hitting CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER since its an Array.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can still edit your question after you've posted it (simply click on the small `edit` hyperlink below the question).